# I want to add default column in output in sql

Tags: sql

I want to add default column in output:

```
awbno     booking_date    Inscan_date    DR_date          
-----------------------------------------------------
111       10/03/2017      10/03/2017    15/02/2017  
222        is null        15/03/2017     is null       
333       05/04/2017       is null      17/02/2017  
444       15/02/2017       15/02/2017    18/02/2017 
555        is null         16/02/2017    19/02/2017    
666      28/02/2017        17/02/2017     20/02/2017    
777      01/03/2017        18/02/2017      is null
```

I want to output like this way:

```
awbno     booking_date     Inscan_date    DR_date        default
-----------------------------------------------------------------
111       10/03/2017       10/03/2017    15/02/2017 
222        is null         15/03/2017    is null       booking_Inscan_fail
333       05/04/2017       is null       17/02/2017      Inscan_fail
444       15/02/2017       15/02/2017    18/02/2017 
555        is null         16/02/2017    19/02/2017     booking_fail
666       28/02/2017       17/02/2017    20/02/2017 
777       01/03/2017       18/02/2017    is null        Dr_fail
```

Comment: Add a case expression to the select list.

Comment: how to use case statement???

Comment: which sql dialect are you using? mysql, mssql, oracle?

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try it like this:

```
 SELECT awbno
 , booking_date
 , Inscan_date
 , DR_date
 , NULLIF(CASE WHEN booking_date IS NULL THEN 'booking_' ELSE '' END 
        + CASE WHEN Inscan_date IS NULL THEN 'Inscan_' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN DR_date IS NULL THEN 'DR_' ELSE '' END,'') + 'fail' AS 'Result'
FROM SomeTable
```

The query will concatenate a string, where all NULL values lead to an entry.

If every column has got a value, the result will be an empty string. `NULLIF` will return `NULL` in this case, so the `+ 'fail'` will return `NULL` too.

Comment: Now I need to give you +1 as well, because I also think your approach is better ;) - only thing: "+" might not work in all sql dialects and you might need to use concat

Comment: @edi But - to be honest - with `CONCAT()` the implicit return of `NULL` in string concatenation via `+` would not work... So the `IFNULL` approach might not even work... This is a good example, why the question's tag should show the specific RDBMS (product and version) :-D

Answer (score 1):

From my understand you might need somthing like this:

```
SELECT awbno
 , booking_date
 , Inscan_date
 , DR_date
 , CONCAT(
    (CASE WHEN booking_date IS NULL THEN 'booking_' ELSE ''), 
    (CASE WHEN WHEN Inscan_date IS NULL THEN 'Inscan_' ELSE ''), 
    (CASE WHEN DR_date IS NULL THEN 'Dr_' ELSE ''),
    (CASE WHEN Inscan_date IS NULL OR
               booking_date IS NULL OR
               DR_date IS NULL THEN 'fail' ELSE '')
 ) as default
FROM <yourtable>
```

which adds `'booking_'`, `'Inscan_'` or `'Dr_'` when one or more of the columns get null.

Comment: true ... will fix it

Comment: Now it's a valid solution, +1 from my side (Although I like my `IFNULL()` approach more :-D ) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try This : You need multiple combinations for given values

```
SELECT CASE 
               WHEN booking_date IS NULL AND Inscan_date IS NULL AND DR_date IS NULL 
               THEN 'booking_Inscan_fail'
               WHEN booking_date IS NULL AND Inscan_date IS NOT NULL AND DR_date IS NOT NULL
               THEN THEN 'booking_fail'
               WHEN booking_date IS NULL AND Inscan_date IS NULL AND DR_date IS NOT NULL
               THEN THEN 'booking_Inscan_fail' 
               WHEN booking_date IS NULL AND Inscan_date IS NOT NULL AND DR_date IS NULL
               THEN THEN 'booking_DR_fail' 
               WHEN booking_date IS NOT NULL AND Inscan_date IS NULL AND DR_date IS NOT NULL
               THEN THEN 'Inscan_fail'    
               WHEN booking_date IS NOT NULL AND Inscan_date IS NULL AND DR_date IS NULL
               THEN THEN 'Inscan_DR_fail' 
               WHEN booking_date IS NOT NULL AND Inscan_date IS NOT NULL AND DR_date IS NULL
               THEN THEN 'DR_fail' 
        END
```

Comment: I do not think that you really must hard-code all possible combinations...

Comment: I thought same when I see sample data of OP, then I realize that there are only 3 columns which are only possible value combinations

Comment: Well, this is a valid solution, just a lot to type... :-D +1 from my side

Comment: Thx @Shnugo, Just Google it use of NullIF, your approach is more generous +1 for you :p